# Metadata for Home Page assigned as Org Default

Tags: lightning, home-page-component, flexipages, home-page-layout, lightning-home-page

I have assigned new **Home Page Flexipage** and activated/assigned it as an **Org Default**.

Unfortunately I cannot find any metadata that contains this assignment.
I can see that per objects, org defaults assignments are in object's meta as an Action Override, but I cannot find this anywhere for Home Page.
Tried also downloading all org metadata files and find any reference of home page api name but found nothing.

Is this even possible? If not, should I use app/profile assignment as a workaround to store this meta in repository?

Thanks!